# Django - How to retrieve columns in template automatically from a query in views.py?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

There is a module with 30 columns.
I query this table in the views.py to get the last record (last row).
To get the data in template (index.html), I have to write each column and in front of it, its value. I have to do it 30 times!
is there anything like  {{form}} to get all the columns and their value automatically or at least by using {% for ... %}?

in views.py

```
def articlesindex(request):    
    data = Articles.objects.all().last()
    return render(request, 'Articles\index.html', {'articles':data})
```

in index.html

```
{{ articles }}   (does not work)
{{ articles.a_table }} (does not work)
 {% for k,v in articles %} (does not work)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ k }}</td>
            <td>{{ v }}</td>
        </tr>
```

{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

That is because `last()` return a single object in a queryset (see the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.last)). So, as it is a single object you will have a single row. You can render the object as follow:

```
<tr>
   <td>{{ articles.attr_1 }}</td>
   <td>{{ articles.attr_2 }}</td>
   ...
   <td>{{ articles.attr_n }}</td>
</tr>
```

The attribute one by one